# ASP MVC Area with RoutingConfig

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-mvc-areas

I'm going to use **Area** in my **ASP.Net MVC** project, but I'm not sure Can I do what I want, or no? because I'm new in MVC.
So I have some Name in my database like this :
Name1
Name2
Name5  and so on

So I want to use area and have a url like this:
www.mysite.com/Name1/Home/Index

User can change **Name1** , How can I check in database if **Name1** Exist ? I mean where can I check this?

My AreaRegistration likes this:

```
public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context) 
{
    context.MapRoute(
        "MyArea_default",
        "{arename}/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        new {action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to achieve the desired functionality you would have to create a custom route constraint. This is explained in depth at http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/controllers-and-routing/creating-a-custom-route-constraint-cs :)

You would perform the check against your existing database records in the Match() method. Please refer to the provided documentation for further explanation :) It's a pretty easy read.

Comment: I Follow the instruction, but **IRouteConstraint** won't fire for me, Where should I use it to handle AreaNames ?